# Getting the text field value and manipulate it

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am new on Rails, I need to implement one solution as a part of project.

I have declare variable and assigned value to it.

```
@variable = "TEXT"
```

and then there is a text box field where the value is equal to `@variable`

```
<input id="textfield" type="text" name="textfield" value="<%= @variable %>">
```

Now, I want to check whether the textfield value has changed or not. If it has changed then I need to override `@variable` and set it equal to the text which is entered, else I need to go with default value what is initialized.

**I have tried to use `onblur()` but don't know how to get the textfield value in rails variable and override it.**

I need to do this because, There is another script which is taking `@variable` as one of the parameter.

Comment: Once you submit the form, in the controller you can access the value which is stored in `params[: textfield]`

Comment: I want to make it dynamic without submitting the button. Any way to do that ?

Comment: Javascript. But it's unclear what you are asking since `@variable` is a Ruby variable. And the other script you are mentioning is it Ruby or Javascript or what else? You tagget ruby-on-rails

Comment: It's ROR Project and script which im talking about is JS

Answer (score 0):

First set the initial value and then onblur check if it is changed:

```
<input id="textfield" type="text" name="textfield" value="<%= @variable %>" onblur="changed(this);">

VALUE = document.getElementById('textfield').value;

function changed(e){
  if(e.value == VALUE){
    // Do nothing if value is not changed
  } else {
    Rails.ajax({
      url: "url for the page",
      type: "GET",
      data: "variable=" + e.value,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Now in the controller you can access the params and overwrite the variable.